# Метод matches строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка из которой нужно выбрать все слова, которые начинаются с большой буквы и записать в новую строку, а с маленькой также в новую строку.
Понимаю, что нужно использовать регулярные выражения, но к сожалению из этого ничего не получилось

Данный код выводит все слова которые начинаются с большой буквы в новую строку, но как вывести остальные слова, которые начинаются с маленькой буквы в другую строку?

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile ("[A-Z][a-z]+");
Matcher m= p1.matcher("Dont be shy Just be yourself");

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.print(m.group());
}
```

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: Первоначально были попытки хотя-бы найти слова, которые начинаются с большой буквы.         
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile ("[A-Z]");
       Matcher m= p1.matcher("Don`t be shy Just be yourself");
 
                      while (m.find())
                      {
                      System.out.print(m.group());
                      }         
        }
    }

Comment: @Quest, приложите Ваши попытки в тело вопроса (не все читают комментарии). Это поможет другим понять с чем именно у Вас возникли проблемы. Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Символ ^ в квадратных скобках - означает `всё кроме`...
те ваше регулярное выражение значит - `всё кроме больших букв`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yIwcAz/2
Что то похожее, но сразу говорю - можно сделать лучше =)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yIwcAz/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, которое вам требуется:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<capital>[A-Z][a-z']*)|(?<regular>[a-z']+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Don't be shy. Just be yourself.");

StringBuilder capital = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder regular = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String upper = matcher.group("capital");
    String lower = matcher.group("regular");
    if (upper != null) {
        capital.append(upper).append(' ');
    } else {
        regular.append(lower).append(' ');
    }
}
if (capital.length() > 0) {
    capital.setLength(capital.length() - 1);
}
if (regular.length() > 0) {
    regular.setLength(regular.length() - 1);
}

System.out.println(capital);
System.out.println(regular);
```

Напечатает:

```
Don't Just
be shy be yourself
```

Answer (score -1):

Если не получается с регулярными выражениями, может будет полезен вариант без них. Вы можете использовать метод `Character.isUpperCase(char);`

```
    String text = "aaa Bbb cCc";
    String[] split = text.split(" ");
    StringBuilder upBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder lowBuilder  = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : split){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0))) upBuilder.append(word + " ");
        else lowBuilder.append(word + " ");
    }

    System.out.println(upBuilder.toString().trim());
    System.out.println(lowBuilder.toString().trim());
```

или вот вариант с выражениями и удалением знаков припинания

```
    String text = "Aaa,    ;;;Bbb---+ - cCc;;dDD";
    text = " " + text;
    text = text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");

    String up = text.replaceAll("\\W[a-z][A-z]*", "");
    up = up.replaceAll("\\p{Space}+", " ").trim();

    String low = text.replaceAll("\\W[A-Z][A-z]*", "");
    low = low.replaceAll("\\p{Space}+", " ").trim();

    System.out.println(up);
    System.out.println(low);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили, но все же хочется понять как до конца довести используя регулярные выражения

Comment: Вырезав из строки все ненужное мы получим искомый результат.

Comment: Да, уже сделано. Спасибо